# Relationship to an Identity Column that is not a primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a `Customers` table where `ID` (`INT`) is an `Identity` column (1,1) and `CustomerID` (`NVARCHAR`) is the primary key. I have a second table with `CustID` (`INT`) and I would like to create a relationship to `Customers` table's `ID` column.

I have been notified by SQL Server Management Studio that there is no matching primary key or unique constraint - so I added the constraint on the ID column of `Customers` to make it unique. Same message.

[image: primary key or unique constraint error]

EDIT Adding my SQL scripts for tables, constraints and relationship

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers]
(
    [CustomerID] [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyName] [nvarchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [ContactName] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [ContactTitle] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [Address2] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [State] [char](2) NULL,
    [Region] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [PostalCode] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [Country] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [Phone] [nvarchar](24) NULL,
    [Fax] [nvarchar](24) NULL,
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Customers] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CustomerID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [ID_Unique] 
        UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customers] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Customers_State]  DEFAULT ('VA') FOR [State]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customers]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_CustomersStates] 
        FOREIGN KEY([State]) REFERENCES [dbo].[States] ([Abbrev])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customers] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CustomersStates]
GO


-- =======================================================================

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Quote]
(
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Number] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [SalesPersonId] [int] NULL,
    [CustId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Status] [int] NULL,
    [QuoteDate] [datetime] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Quote] 
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Quote]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_Quote_tbl_SalesPerson] 
       FOREIGN KEY([SalesPersonId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[SalesPerson] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Quote] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_Quote_tbl_SalesPerson]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Quote]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_Quote_tbl_Status] 
        FOREIGN KEY([Status]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Status] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Quote] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_Quote_tbl_Status]
GO

-- ================================================================

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[States]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Abbrev] [char](2) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_States_1] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Abbrev] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

-- ==================================================================

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Status]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Status_Id] 
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

--------- ==========================================================

ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERS
Add  Constraint ID_Unique UNIQUE (ID)

-- =========================================================================

ALTER TABLE QUOTE

 ADD CONSTRAINT  FK_QuoteCustId_CustomerId
    FOREIGN KEY (CustId)
    REFERENCES dbo.CUSTOMERS (ID)
    ON DELETE  NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE  NO ACTION
```

Comment: Why would the `ID` in `Customers` table not the `CustomerID`??

Comment: @Eric because often often a "CustomerID" is externally (and previously) defined.

Comment: Sounds like you have your FK references backwards.  Can you show us the actual command you are using?

Comment: You added *what* constraint on the `ID` field of `Customers`?   Show us the constraint.   The behavior you describe is unreproducible.

Comment: @TabAlleman I posted the complete create tables etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

```
create table tmp.Customer(ID  INT identity(1,1) , CustID varchar(8) primary key);
GO
create table tmp.Second(blah int, RefCustID INT);
GO
Create unique index UX1 on tmp.Customer(ID)
GO
ALTER TABLE tmp.Second
ADD CONSTRAINT whatever
FOREIGN KEY (RefCustID) 
REFERENCES tmp.Customer(ID)
GO
```

I suspect that you have swapped the positions of the `Customer` and `Second` table names in the ALTER TABLE command that creates the Foreign Key.  (this is more common than you would think)

In response to a question in the comments, I changed the unique index to a unique constraint and retried it, still works.

```
create table tmp.Customer(ID  INT identity(1,1) , CustID varchar(8) primary key);
GO
create table tmp.Second(blah int, RefCustID INT);
GO
Alter table Tmp.Customer  ADD Constraint UX1 Unique (ID)
GO
ALTER TABLE tmp.Second
ADD CONSTRAINT whatever
FOREIGN KEY (RefCustID) 
REFERENCES tmp.Customer(ID)
GO
```

The other possibility here is that your datatypes do not match.  You would have to provide the table definitions for us to check that.

Comment: You are using ID as the primary Key - in my table - the Primary Key is CustomerID Nvarchar(5) and the ID column is the Identity (1,1) - I know if I make the Primary key my Identity column - the relationship is allowed and works. Because a primary key by default is unique. Now why is it the ID column when set to unique is not being allowed ?

Comment: @Ken OK, I fixed it and re-tested it.  Works for me.

Comment: @Ken as I said, check the command that is creating the Foreign Key, I suspect you have the Referenc*ing* and Referenc*ed* tables reversed.

Comment: Looking at your script - Unique Index versus Unique constraint on a column ?? I know the index is used for searching but doesn't the message tell me I need a Unique Constraint rather than an Index ?

Comment: I tried with a unique constraint instead, still works.

Comment: My constraint is the same as yours - however I closed my diagramming window  (no changes)  and ran it again and now it works.. MS -SQL_MS ??? Aaargh..??

Comment: @Ken I'd guess that it had not saved the changes back yet.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is unreproducible.

I took the code from your question, changed the order of the CREATE TABLE statements so that the `Status` and `State` table were created before `Customer`.    And I also took out the creation of the duplicate Constraint:

```
--this already exists
 CONSTRAINT [ID_Unique] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

--so don't create this
 ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERS
Add  Constraint ID_Unique UNIQUE (ID)
```

And I was able to run your code without encountering the error you describe.   The only error I got was creating the FK to `SalesPerson` because you didn't include the DDL for that table.

Therefore there is some difference in the code you are executing and the code you are showing us that is causing your error.

Comment: The code is the same except for the missing tables - I scripted them directly from the tables themselves - of course not in order and salesperson was accidentally omitted. I closed the Diagramming window in MGmnt Studio - no changes and now it works .. ???###??? Aaargh